# Redshift JDBC connection crashes on second opening in R

Tags: r, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am using the `RJDBC` package to connect to AWS Redshift from an EC2 ubuntu instance.

I can successfully connect using the `JDBC()` call, retrieve/insert rows and then close the connection.

However, when I re-open a second connection in the same R session, R crashes with a segmentation fault.  This happens in both R Studio and console R.  I'm using conda to manage the R.

I have tried the connection using the native redshift `jar` provided by Amazon and also another `jar` from Progess Software.  I get the same effect with both drivers:  first connection is fine, subsequent connections crash.

I've installed the latest JVM v8.  I had seen some other threads that suggested installing v6 as a workaround, but unfortunately that is no longer available at the oracle site.

My gut feeling is that Java has a weird interaction with R, but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this myself and thought I'd record in case this is useful to others.

The problem was really with `rJava` not re-initialising the JVM correctly.

I added the following line before opening a database connection:

```
 rJava::.jinit(force.init = TRUE)
```

Now I can open and close connections without issue using `RJDBC`